# Вешать скрипт на копию объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть спавнер, и нужно чтоб он через время удалял объект что заспавнил, и вот я думаю.
как мне повесить скрипт на уже СОЗДАННУЮ КОПИЮ, или как-то указать ее.
в скрипте самого спавнера просто прописать

```
        `LifeTime += 1f * Time.deltaTime;
        if (LifeTime >= EndTime) 
        {
            Destroy (Object.gameObject);
        }`
```

недостаточно, он просто удаляет именно шаблон с которого и создается копия.

То ли я дурак, то ли лыжи и в действительности не едут, а если и едут то в обратную сторону моего развития, по всей видимости.
Я находил что-то похожее, но там лишь удаление САМОГО объекта, а мне лишь нужно через время удалять ту копию что создал спавнер.
Корутины и триггер что будет удалять их не предлагать, ничего не меняется от этого, я пробовал уже.
а триггер мне попросту не подходит, по определенным причинам

Comment: ну во первых у функции `Destroy()` есть перегрузка с временем удаления(`Destroy(object, 3f)`), а во вторых при создании объекта записывай в какую нибудь переменную типа твоего скрипта, который ты хочешь чтобы был на нем, т.е. есть скрипт Bullet  и ты пишешь значит вот так `Bullet newBullet = Instantiate(_bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject enemyPrefab;
    private GameObject _enemy;
 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(_enemy == null)
        {
            _enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab) as GameObject;
            _enemy.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 2, 0);
            float angle = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 360);
            _enemy.transform.Rotate(0, angle, 0);
        }
    }
```

Сериализованная переменная для связи с объектом шаблоном.
Закрытая переменная для слежения за экземпляром врага в сцене.
В условие: порождаем нового врага, только если враг на сцене отсутствует.
При помощи метода Instantiate, копируем шаблон.

Я тоже новичок, но достичь подобной цели, мне помогло.

Comment: возможно это то что мне нужно, но дело в том что мне удалить надо просто объект через время, а куда я впихнуть это в вашем скрипте, не особо понимаю